Как сделать меню, которое сворачивается в подменю при уменьшении ширины?
У меня есть горизонтальное меню. Я хочу, чтобы при уменьшении ширины невлезающий элемент уходил в подменю. Чтобы при этом появилась кнопка "Еще". Я могу по ней кликнуть и открыть подменю.
Нужно что-то такое:

Примерно понимаю, что как-то надо следить за переполнением.
Работаю с vue.

на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Ставьте EvenListener на ширину экрана. Ширина табов меню фиксирована - делите ширину экрана на ширину таба по Math.floor -получаете количество показа. Для показа будет два 

Вот что-то похожее на Вашу задумку - тык
Думаю Вы без проблем сможете портировать это во Vue
